# Check other sheet's rows using numbers from cell from current sheet. Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to create some SUM calculations using rows from another sheet but those row numbers would be identified on the current sheets. This is what I'm trying to do which is causing an error:

`=SUM(Calculations!F(C7):F(C8))`

Where F is the column on sheet Calculations and C7 and C8 are the columns on the current sheet which would have a row number on them. For example if cells C7 and C8 are 3 and 4 respectively then I'd like the formula to check F3 and F4 on the sheet labelled 'Calculations'

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use INDIRECT:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Calculations!F"&C7&":F"&C8))
```